# Relative Uri in WPF Translates into Wrong Absolute Directory

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uri

I have a custom control with property of type Uri. When I set this Uri to a relative path `"InterfaceImages/Wait.gif"`, I would expect it to translate into the current directory when I use it to open that file. The expected directory would look something like this:

```
C:\Users\MyUsername\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\InterfaceGraphics\Wait.gif
```

but instead, WPF mangles it into this:

```
              //-->Note the lowercased filenames<--//
C:\Users\MyUsername\documents\visual studio 2012\Projects\MySolution\MyProject\bin\Debug\InterfaceGraphics\Wait.gif
```

causing the application to throw an exception: "Could not find a part of the path '[path-shown-above]'."

NOWHERE in my code do I mess with the current directory. So why is it doing this?

I don't know how relevant this is, but the function call that throws it is:

```
_gifDecoder = new GifBitmapDecoder(this.GifSource, BitmapCreateOptions.PreservePixelFormat, BitmapCacheOption.Default);
```

where `this.GifSource` is a property of type `System.Uri`, and the XAML that creates the item and sets the property looks like this:

```
<local:GifImage x:Name="WaitIcon" HorizontalAlignment="Center"
        Height="100" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="100"
        MaxWidth="100" MaxHeight="100"
        GifSource="InterfaceGraphics/Wait.gif"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, the working directory is the one containing the executable. The executable generated by Visual Studio is in the bin/Debug (or bin/Release) subfolder of your project, so that's your working directory. Since the absolute path is the combination of the working directory and the relative path, what you're seeing is perfectly normal.

You have several options:

- set the "copy to output directory" property to true on the project items that you want available in the executable's directory
- change the working directory in the project's debug properties to be the project directory, rather than the output directory
- embed the images in your app as resources (you will need to change the code accordingly to load the images)

BTW, if you want to display animated GIF images, you can use my [WpfAnimatedGif](https://github.com/thomaslevesque/WpfAnimatedGif) library, which does exactly that. It is also [available as a NuGet package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/WpfAnimatedGif).

Comment: Oh gosh. what a stupid moment of mine. How did I forget about the project vs. build phenomenon? :p Still, I HAVE tried setting the image file to build as a resource, and referencing it accordingly in code. I should post another question about that, because I did everything as instructed in MS documentation, tutorials, etc... and it just kept yelling at me that the Uri was empty.

Comment: I also intend to try your library. Question: does it handle gif frame durations/offsets/etc. or does it just assume a constant framerate like IE and other such microsoft apps?

Comment: @FireWingLead, yes, it handles just about everything about GIF animations, including frame durations, partial frames, various frame disposal methods, etc.